# Forward chat functionality with quickblox

Tags: android, quickblox

I am developing android application like whatsapp.

I want to forward my chat to another user. For that I have used quickblox account. But I don't understand how to do forward functionality like whatsApp does.

Can you please help me?

Thanks,

Comment: Will you please provide some more information that what have you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Server saves chat history. You may only save necessary messages or fields (as json file for example) and send it to another user or via email (using Android tools)